# .withButtons() is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

Am trying to export my datatable into excel or csv but when I use .withButtons(), I get an error saying its not a function
    The dependencies added are:

```
<script src="{context.links.resourceBaseUrl|s}/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{context.links.resourceBaseUrl|s}/vendor/datatables.net-buttons-bs/buttons.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="{context.links.resourceBaseUrl|s}/vendor/datatables.net-buttons-bs/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{context.links.resourceBaseUrl|s}/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{context.links.resourceBaseUrl|s}/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{context.links.resourceBaseUrl|s}/vendor/jszip/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{context.links.resourceBaseUrl|s}/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{context.links.resourceBaseUrl|s}/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{context.links.resourceBaseUrl|s}/vendor/datatables/angular-datatables/plugins/buttons/angular-datatables.buttons.min.js"></script>
```

And my columns are defined as below

```
 $scope.dtColumnDefs = {
          open: [
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notSortable(),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2).notSortable(),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(5).notSortable(),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(6).notSortable(),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(7).notSortable()
          ],
          closed: [
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notSortable(),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2).notSortable(),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(5).notSortable(),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(8).notSortable(),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(9).notSortable(),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(10).notSortable(),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(11).notSortable(),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(12).notSortable()
          ]
        }
```

And my controller code

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withDOM('Blrtip')
        .withButtons([{
            title : 'liveissues',
            text:'Export To CSV',
            exportOptions: 
               {
              columns:[1,2,5]}                                 
                }         
        ]);
```

I do not have datatables and datatables.buttons injected in angular.module. When I add them I get a blank page with out any console error
Can someone help?I tried what ever I know and I could not progress further